# Finding Latest Opportunity Using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are sending emails to opportunity's primary contact using Journey Builder. So when a new opportunity is created and the stage is 'stg1', the primary contact is injected in the journey.

In reality, there could be multiple opportunities associated with a Contact, so I want to pick up the opportunity which was just created (which got injected in the journey).

How do I find that most recent opportunity using AMPScript? 
I am using [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects()**](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/salesforce/RetrieveSalesforceObjects.html) on Opportunity and using other fields from the object also

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Data Stream](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources/), you may be able to use [LookupOrderedRows()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/LookupOrderedRows.html).

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
  set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
  set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
  set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

 next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

 No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Not using datastream

Comment: May be worth it to get it configured.  Another option could be retrieve all of the rows for the Contact with AMPScript, build a JSON object string and then use SSJS to sort it.

Comment: Hi Adam, is there any AMPScript function to find the no. Of rows returned by RetrieveSalesforceObjects() ?

Comment: Yes. Rowcount()